# Adverb: the cornea "ideally should be perfectly" round like a ping-pong ball

Tags: word-usage

The cornea is a part of the human eye ball, in particular, the front
window of the eye, shown as the following image

[image]

to describe and explain the cornea this way

> the cornea **ideally
>   should be perfectly** round like a
>   ping-pong ball

Is it grammatical and idiomatic to say "ideally should be perfectly"? In particular, are the adverbs, "ideally" and "perfectly", in the correct position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the adverbs are correct for the meaning. The cornea should be perfectly round for best vision and uniform focus.  The fact is that corneas aren't always perfectly round and getting the best vision requires corrective lenses. The word "ideally" qualifies "should be perfectly round", recognizing that that isn't always the case.